# Question on how to find basis for set of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $W = P_2(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose $U$ is the subspace of $L(V,W)$ (the set of all linear transformations from $V$ to $W$) spanned by $T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4$ where $$T_1((a,b)) = (a+b)+ax^2~~~T_2((a,b)) = (a+b)+(a+b)x-bx^2$$ $$T_3((a,b)) = (a+b)(x-x^2)~~~T_4 = 2(a+b)+(a+b)x+(a-b)x^2$$ for $(a,b) \in V$. Find a basis for $U$.

After working out till my last step, i guessed that $T_1,T_2$ are linearly independent and hence form a basis for $U$. However, i do not know how to derive this answer by using any known Theorem. Attached is my working:[image]

Comment: A basis is a linearly independent set of vectors whose span is the entire subspace. Does $\{T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4\}$ work?

Comment: No they are not linearly independent.

Comment: $T_2-T_1$ is $T_3$, if I'm doing my math right (you should check this). So the only possible bases we can make are $\{T_1,T_2\}$ and $\{T_1,T_2,T_4\}$. If the latter set is linearly independent, it's that one; if it's not, then the first one forms a basis, because you already checked that it was linearly independent.

Comment: But my problem is how do I know they are linearly independent by using my working? This question is a bit different from the usual vector questions where I can just chug them and solve using Gaussian and the pivot columns/rows will just be the linearly independent ones. For this I am not sure how to see if they are linearly independent.  Sure , when I “Guess and check” $T_1,T_2$ they do have trivial solution but I wish to have a more compact way to solve it.

Comment: I don't know where you are in your course, but there is a statement that these sorts of linear transformations can be written as matrices. Then you can rewrite the matrices as vectors in a vector space, and apply your normal tools. Let me give an example: $T_1$ takes $(a,b)$ to $a+b+ax^2$, so it's a linear transformation of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\ 0 & 0\\ 1 &0\\ \end{pmatrix}$$.